# How to select a row in a table and select a specific radio button next to it

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I would like to select a specific row in a table on a website and select a button next to it. The problem I have is each time I select the button it remembers the last button by position `xpath=(//a[@id='DeleteLnkBtn'])[4]` but i would like to select the row by name and select the button unique to that row. There are multiple rows with the same buttons all having the same name (Delete).

`HTML`:

```
<td>Auto Missed Session 2</td> <a id="DeleteLnkBtn" >Delete</a>
```

My aim is to reference the row by a text in the table "Auto Missed Session 2" and click on the delete button.

Here is what I've tried so far.

Option 1 - `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td[contains(text() = 'Auto Missed ssion 2', + 'DeleteLnkBtn')]")).click();`

Option 2 - `driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//tr/td[contains(text(),'Auto Missed Session 2' + 'Delete')])")).click();`

The above fails stating this is not a valid Xpath expresssion on Option 1 and No such element: unable to locate element on Option 2

The table data looks like this 
td> Auto Missed Session 2 /td> - This is the name of the row in the table i would like to select.

`a id= "DeleteLnkBtn"`  This is the button i would like to select.

Xpath of the button is `//*[@id="DeleteLnkBtn"]`

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share `HTML` code for the same?

Comment: <td>Auto Missed Session 2</td>
<a id="DeleteLnkBtn" >Delete</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code and let me know the result:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text() = 'Auto Missed Session 2']/following::a[text()='Delete']")).click();
```

Comment: Thank you Andersson, much appreciated. I guess my  xpath was poorly written, I am new to this. Thanks once again

Comment: Hi Andersson - Is it possible to add multiple td in order to reference the delete button by its unique identifiers such as  <td>Auto Missed Session 2</td> and <td>06/03/2017</td>  <td>10:00:00</td> Which would represent Person, Date and time?

Comment: If those `td` elements are siblings, then you might try `"//td[text() = 'Auto Missed Session 2']/following-sibling::td[text()="06/03/2017"]/following-sibling::td[text()="10:00:00"]/following::a[text()='Delete']"`